# Unexpected token when switching to develop branch

Tags: node.js

I installed a new website using the following command. But when I try to create a develop branch I get some weird error.

```
gatsby new static-website https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default
```

When I try to switch to develop branch I get the following error.

```
root@app01:~/static-website# gatsby develop
gatsby develop

Start development server. Watches files, rebuilds, and hot reloads if something changes

Options:
  --verbose                   Turn on verbose output                                                                                                   [boolean] [default: false]
  --no-color, --no-colors     Turn off the color in output                                                                                             [boolean] [default: false]
  -H, --host                  Set host. Defaults to localhost                                                                                     [string] [default: "localhost"]
  -p, --port                  Set port. Defaults to 8000                                                                                               [string] [default: "8000"]
  -o, --open                  Open the site in your (default) browser for you.                                                                                          [boolean]
  -S, --https                 Use HTTPS. See https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/local-https/ as a guide                                                                      [boolean]
  -c, --cert-file             Custom HTTPS cert file (relative path; also required: --https, --key-file). See https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/local-https/   [string] [default: ""]
  -k, --key-file              Custom HTTPS key file (relative path; also required: --https, --cert-file). See https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/local-https/   [string] [default: ""]
  --open-tracing-config-file  Tracer configuration file (OpenTracing compatible). See https://gatsby.dev/tracing                                                         [string]
  -h, --help                  Show help                                                                                                                                 [boolean]
  -v, --version               Show version number                                                                                                                       [boolean]
error There was a problem loading the local develop command. Gatsby may not be installed. Perhaps you need to run "npm install"?


  Error: /root/static-website/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/reporter/loggers/ink/index.js:13111
    const lineNumber = location?.start.line;
                                ^
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

  - loader.js:915 wrapSafe
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16

  - loader.js:963 Module._compile
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27

  - loader.js:1027 Object.Module._extensions..js
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10

  - loader.js:863 Module.load
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32

  - loader.js:708 Function.Module._load
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14

  - loader.js:887 Module.require
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19

  - helpers.js:74 require
    internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18

  - start-logger.js:41 startLogger
    [static-website]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/reporter/start-logger.js:41:5

  - index.js:15 Object.<anonymous>
    [static-website]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/reporter/index.js:15:30

  - loader.js:999 Module._compile
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30
```

Any idea how to resolve the issue? I tested gatsby@2.5.0 and also the latest version. Same error.

```
root@app01:~/static-website# npm list -g --depth=0
/usr/local/lib
└── gatsby-cli@2.5.0

root@app01:~/static-website# npm list -g --depth=0
/usr/local/lib
└── gatsby-cli@5.2.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

When we install nodejs on ubuntu 22.04 using `apt-get` it installs old version (node v12.22.9).

I followed this [documentation](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-22-04/) and installed latest version of nodejs (v18.12.1) and npm (8.19.2).

Now if I run `gatsby develop` there are no errors.